# Is it possible apply NSAppearance.Name.vibrantLight to an NSWindow, and keep controls?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to apply a vibrantLight effect (like the one in the left panel of Xcode) to an NSWindow … and I can get NSAppearance.Name.vibrantLight to work in the NSWindow:

```
if(olt_THE_TEST_WINDOW == nil){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TEST_WINDOW",owner:self,topLevelObjects:nil)
}

let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
visualEffect.blendingMode = .behindWindow
visualEffect.state = .active

olt_THE_TEST_WINDOW.contentView?.wantsLayer = true
olt_THE_TEST_WINDOW.appearance = NSAppearance(named:NSAppearance.Name.vibrantLight)
olt_THE_TEST_WINDOW.contentView = visualEffect
olt_THE_TEST_WINDOW.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

…
but my controls on the window disappear.

Is it possible to apply this to the window view and keep the controls?

Thank you.

Comment: The controls are in the content view. Replacing the content view will remove the controls. Why don't you add the `NSVisualEffectView` in the xib?

Comment: oh wow. was not aware of that!  seems to be working, but is it really just as simple as that? seriously all I did was slap NSVisualEffectView on the window, no init or anything. Humm.